# Unpickle object into int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I need to change an object to an int when it gets unpickled.  I'm creating an unpickler and overriding find_global which works when I can unpickle into an arbitrary type.  Returning `int` from `find_global` doesn't work because the unpickler tries to fill its `__dict__` and I get `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__dict__'`.  When the unpickler unpickles this object it calls `__init__` with the int value I want and `set_state` with and empty state.

I need to do this because the object comes from a third-party library and we aren't using the library any more.

```
def find_global(modulename, classname):
    if modulename == 'some.module' and classname == 'ClassThatNeedsToBeAnInt':
        # I need to get the unpickler to unpickle this into a int

unpickler.find_global = find_global
```

I've tried creating a class with a `__new__` method, but even if I return an int the unpickler proceeds to calling `int.set_state`

I have this partial solution, but I would like an actual int.

```
class SubclassedInt(int):
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        pass


def find_global(modulename, classname):
    if modulename == 'some.module' and classname == 'ClassThatNeedsToBeAnInt':
        return SubclassedInt

unpickler.find_global = find_global
```

Comment: What is this object, and do you control its implementation? (And why are you doing this?)

Comment: I've updated the question to answer this.

Comment: Can you reload the pickle with the third-party library and regenerate the pickle? Regenerating the pickle with a patched `__reduce__` may be the easiest way to handle this. (Or replacing the objects with ints directly in the unpickled data structure.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I can't regenerate the pickle when I have access to the library.  I'm probably going to change the unpickled data directly.  It just seems strange I can't use a factory to unpickle into whatever type I like.

Comment: The highly imperative nature of the pickle serialization format makes that kind of thing hard. The basic units say "do this thing", not "here's this data". There are no explicit markers of where any subobject's serialization begins or ends, you can't always even tell what type things will be, and memo optimizations complicate things further.